# concatenate within loop using sed

Tags: loops, sed

I have two types of files (A.n and B). A.n files are named A.1, A.2, A.3 etc.
In B file there is a word like 'Element.xyz'  which I want to replace by 'Element_n.xyz' with all other things unchanged and append below the A.n files. The two added A.n and B files should be named as

```
final.n i.e. final.1, final.2, final.3 etc
```

So `Final.1` file should look like this:

A.1
B file with `Element.txt` is replaced by `Element_1.txt`

I tried with this code but failed:

```
for f in A.*;
sed 's/Element.txt/Element_$f.txt/g' B >> tt;

cat A.$f tt >> final_$f.txt ; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would append more and more data to the file `tt`. Your code would put the output from the `B` file before, not after, the text from the `A` file. Furthermore, the single quotes prevent the variable from being visible to `sed`. If I understand your question correctly, you are looking simply for

```
for f in A.*; do
    n=${f#A.}
    ( cat "$f"
      sed "s/Element.txt/Element_$n.txt/g" B ) >"final_$n".txt
done
```

The parentheses group the two commands so that their output can be redirected together at once. The file name in `$f` contains the `A.` part, so we chop it off with a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and store that in `$n`. The argument to `cat` should obviously be the file name itself.

Comment: Yes , it works fine. This is exactly I want.